# A question of nuance: 'amiable' and amicable'

Tags: adjectives

How would an English-speaking person explain the difference between *amiable* and *amicable*? Which is the more friendly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither is “more friendly”. They aren’t the same, nor are they usually applied to the same situation.

- **People** are called ***amiable*** if they are kindly souls with a friendly and good-natured disposition.
- **Arrangements** are called ***amicable*** if they are settled with mutual goodwill and without adversarial friction.

Comment: Got it! thanks. Googled a bit more (which is what I should have done in the first place) and found this: "A group might have an amicable meeting, because the people there are amiable."

Comment: +1. Since the asker is Swedish, I might add that ‘amiable’ = _vänlig_, whereas ‘amicable’ = _vänskaplig_ in Swedish.

Comment: In order to make the answer more strong, why don't you add a last sentence saying "So, 'amiable' applies to person while 'amicable' to relations between person"?